How to use drizzle-zod with custom types?
I have a custom type (e.g. citext) but drizzle zod is treating it as unknown:
import { customType } from "drizzle-orm/pg-core";

export const citext = customType<{ data: string }>({
  dataType() {
    return "citext";
  },
});


How can I get drizzle-zod to output the correct type? Example usage:
export const team = pgTable("team", {
  id: text("id").primaryKey(),
  name: citext("name").notNull(),
});

export const selectTeamSchema = createSelectSchema(team);

Unfortunately selectTeamSchema's name property is z.ZodAny, and selectTeamSchema.parse({name: undefined}) doesn't e rror, even though I've used notNull

It's not really possible since drizzle-zod just checks the same field (dataType) in this code https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/blob/6adbd78748c8ecb687caa87b7cd775d86cdc0a2b/drizzle-zod/src/index.ts#L202-L237. It doesn't handle citext. We could add it, but citext is pg specific, and this code is generic to all SQL dbs that is supported. More generally, it doesn't really support custom types. It would be nice if we could provide our own zod type here.

Just override the fields with the second argument.
Simple pattern
export const selectTeamSchema = createSelectSchema(team, {
  name: z.string(),
});

For a more complicated project:
const citextFieldOverrides = {
  name: z.string(),
  // It doesn't let you pass arbitrary properties here (type safe)
} as const;

export const insertTeamSchema = createInsertSchema(team, citextFieldOverrides);
export type InsertMessageSchema = z.infer<typeof insertTeamSchema>;
// add types for citext fields, so that they're not unknown in TS and generated OpenAPI.
export const selectTeamSchema = createSelectSchema(team, citextFieldOverrides);
export type SelectTeamSchema = z.infer<typeof selectTeamSchema>;

